# What's My Number (Math Riddle)

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

I am thinking of a number. I multiplied by 3, subtracted by 8, doubled the result, and added 14. Then i added on 50% of what I had and subtracted 11. Then i divided by 5. After all that, I was left with 8.

What number did i start with?

Comment: You do know that this is a basic Algebra problem and not a riddle, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You started with 6. 8*5=40, 40+11=51, 2/3*51=34, 34-14=20, 20/2=10, 10+8=18, 18/3=6.

Comment: i did not understand why you did 2/3*51 , i did not know how to get the original number based on the current number and a percent care to explain?

Comment: Because you took a number x and multiplied it by 1.5 to get 51, that means that 1/3 of 51 would be 1/2 of x, so 2/3 of 51 would be x, which was 34.